# Client not render with initial state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js, react-router-redux

I am trying to build Universal / isomorphic app with React, React-router, Redux and Immutable. I managed to make server render and send back client the initial state along with HTML. But the client seem not to render with that initial state at all.

My server code :

1.Handle route:

```
import {match,RouterContext,Router,Route,browserHistory} from "react-router";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {createStore} from "redux";
import {createRouter} from "../../shared/support/routers";
import reducer from "../../shared/reducer";
import ReactDOMServer  from "react-dom/server";
import React from "react";
import Immutable from "immutable";
import {RenderPage} from "../routes/helper";

function homeRender(req, res) {

    match({routes, location: req.url}, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps)=> {
        if (redirectLocation) {
            //@TODO: response redirect location
            console.log('redirect location');
        }
        if (err) {
            //@TODO: response error
            console.log(err.stack);
        }
        if (!renderProps) {
            //@TODO: route to 404
            console.log("no renderProps");
        }

        Article.getArtilceByPage(1,20)
            .then(questions=>{
                let state = Immutable.fromJS({
                    title:"Home page render on server side",
                    qs:questions
                });
                let store = createStore(reducer,state);
                store.dispatch({
                    type: "SET_STATE",
                    state: state
                });
                let html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <RouterContext {...renderProps}/>
                    </Provider>
                );
                let fullPage = RenderPage(html, store.getState());
                res.end(fullPage);
            })
        .catch(function(e) {
            res.end(e);
        });

    });
}
```

2. render page code: `window.__PRELOADED_STATE__` is rendered on the response's HTML

```
export function RenderPage(content,state) {
    let temp = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>${state.get('title')}</title>
    <meta name='og:title' content='Dont ask me for it'/>
    <script>
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(state)}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='app'><div>${content}</div></div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="manifest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>



  </body>
  </html>`;
    return temp;
}
```

reducer code:

```
import {Map} from "immutable";
export default function (state = Map(), action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_STATE":
            return setState(state,action.state);
        case "HANDLE_CLICK":
            handleClick();
            //console.log("Hello there");
    }
}
//initial state
function setState(state,newState) {
    return state.merge(newState);
}
//handle user click
function handleClick(state,action) {

    console.log("This one could not be pass child comps");

}
```

shared code to create route on both client and server:

```
import {Router,Route} from "react-router";
import React from "react";
import App from "../components/app";
import {HomeContainer} from "../components/home";
import {TagContainer} from "../components/tag";

export function createRouter(hist) {
    const routes = <Route component={App}>
        <Route path="/" component={HomeContainer}/>
        <Route path="tag" name="tag" component={TagContainer}/>
    </Route>;
    return (
        <Router history={hist}>{routes}</Router>
    );
}
```

and finally: the client code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Router,Route,browserHistory } from "react-router";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {createStore} from "redux";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import Immutable from "immutable";
import {createRouter} from "./support/routers";

console.log(windows.__PRELOADED_STATE__);
const state = Immutable.fromJS(window.__PRELOADED_STATE__);
const store = createStore(reducer,state);
const routes = createRouter(browserHistory);


store.dispatch({
    type: "SET_STATE",
    state: state
});
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            {routes}
        </Provider>
        , document.getElementById("app"));
```

the result: client can view the HTML rendered by server. but it cannot initial store / state from the window.**PRELOADED_STATE**. 
I suspect that the code in the index.js file was not run at all.

UPDATED: the code that cause error when trying to handle "HANDLE_CLICK" in reducer: 
home.js

```
import React from "react";
import PureRenderMixin from 'react-addons-pure-render-mixin';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import * as actionCreator from "./support/action_creator";
import HomeList from "./subComponents/homelist";

export class HomeComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.shouldComponentUpdate = PureRenderMixin.shouldComponentUpdate.bind(this);
    }

    getQuestions() {
        return this.props.data.questions || [];
    }

    render() {
        //console.log(this.getQuestions());
        //console.log(this.props.questions);
        //console.log(this.props);
        return <div className="home">
            <h1>kkk</h1>
            <smal>Here is a list for home stuff</smal>
            <HomeList {...this.props}/>
        </div>
    }
}
//<HomeList {...this.props}/>
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        questions: state.get('qs') // this cause error in console devTool
    };
}
export const HomeContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreator)(HomeComp);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGgEG.png)

Comment: Why are you dispatching `'SET_STATE'` after `createStore`?

Comment: Thanks.  I removed dispatch on both client and server code.  Still not working.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you `console.log` the state you're grabbing it off of `windows` which doesn't exist and should throw.

Because the throw breaks the code flow it never gets to the `render` call.

You should always use DevTools to debug your issues. Coding blind is very hard. Knowing why your app isn't working based purely on what output it produces is very hard.

Using a debugging tool, you can inspect variables, set breakpoints, and evaluate ad hoc code. It really is indispensable.

Comment: I try to click on a button call HANDLE_CLICK in reducer and here is the devtool console:"connect.js:323 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined". and the code cause error is :`code`function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        questions: state.get('qs')
    };
}
export const HomeContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreator)(HomeComp); . please refer to updated question for the line of code in home.js

Comment: The line `console.log(windows.__PRELOADED_STATE__);` will throw because `windows` is undefined. Either the code above is not accurately copy-pasted or the client has no store. Considering your client seems to be reaching `mapStateToProps`, it seems your code isn't quite up to date.

Comment: I have removed the console.log line and still cannot create store on client side. How to create store on client from window.__PRELOADED_STATE__??

Comment: How, may I ask, did you ever have a store or `ReactDOM.render` call if you were accessing `windows.__PRELOADED_STATE__` in a preceding line, a variable that clearly wouldn't be accessible and would therefore surely throw an error? It seems to me the code above wouldn't work at all. Please update the question to only contain code which you actually have and not old code. The question is clearly regarding new code that is not present in the question. Your question cannot be addressed at all with the code you have here.